# Acoustic difference in breathing in and breathing out

Tags: phonetics, acoustic-analysis

Many people can distinguish whether a person is inhaling or exhaling only by audio, even when the tongue and the lip position (=formants) is the same. That must mean there is a difference in the acoustics of it. I wonder what differences are there between the sound of inhaling and that of exhaling.

Comment: I believe that certain African languages have an initial inhaled m or n. Am I right?

Comment: Related: [Distinguishing inhalation and exhalation in Praat](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/13144/distinguishing-inhalation-and-exhalation-in-praat)

Comment: Nope. No language uses ingressive lung air as a linguistic property; however, words in Norwegian can be inhaled for a certain pragmatic effect that I don't understand (disagreement or something like that).

Comment: I think you mean implosives maybe? Anyway, this can't be an answer by this site's [standards](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/help/answering), unfortunately.

Comment: And anyhow, there are no nasal implosives.

Comment: @user6726 How about the ``/ | /`` and ``/ ! /`` in some African languages, aren't they considered as ingressive?

Comment: The ingression is accomplished by oral rarification via jaw lowering, not inhaling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any elastic parts of the vocal apparatus that are not symmetrically perpendicular to the airflow will vibrate differently when they point upstream than when they point downstream.